# Laravel - Consulta com 3 tabelas (1-N)

Tags: laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Estou tentando relacionar estas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é mostrar:

```
Nome,Descrição,Parcela,Valor
```

Model Cliente:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{

    public function recebtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Recebto','id_cliente');
    }

}
```

Model Recebto:

```
class Recebto extends Model
{
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente','id_cliente');
    }

    public function parcelas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RecebtoParcela','id_recebto');
    }
}
```

Model Parcelas:

```
class RecebtoParcela extends Model
{
    public function recebto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recebto','id_recebto');
    }
}
```

No Controller:

```
class RecebtoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $recebtos = Recebto::paginate(15);
        return view('recebtos.index',compact('recebtos'));
    }
```

Só que assim, se um recebimento tem mais de uma parcela, na view só aparece uma delas. O que posso fazer para que todas as parcelas sejam mostradas?

Comment: Preciso saber da `view` como você fez, porque é assim falta você colocar também `with` nas duas relações.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a busca do array com todas as parcelas de um recebimento, basta usar na controller o `with`

Por exemplo na busca de um recebimento específico

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $recebtos = Recebto::with('parcelas')
                ->find($id);
}
```